# Overload function based on the value of the argument

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I know function overloading is dependant on the types of the arguments, but I was wondering if there was anyway you could overload a function based on its argument's value.

I call this "overloading", but this, unlike normal function overloading, would be solved at runtime.

An example where this would be useful:

Say you are creating your own programming language and want to process particular keywords.
It would be nice to write code like this:

```
void process(Keyword keyword);
void process("let") {
/* Some stuff */

}
void process("=") {
/* Some other stuff */
}
void process(default) {
}
```

And when you call process() this code

```
int main() {
   Keyword keyword;
   process(keyword);

}
```

would get converted to:

```
void process_let() {/* Some stuff */}
void process_=() {/* Some other stuff*/}
void process_default() {}
int main() {
    Keyword keyword;
    switch (keyword) {
        case "let" : process_let(); break;
        case "="   : process_=(); break;
        case default" process_default(); break;
    }
}
```

Of course, the implementation of such a value-overloaded function could be and is probably different, but the above code what just to give you an idea of what I wanted to happen when I called process.

Is there a way to do this?? Maybe with some template black magic? This does look like a problem solvable by templates but the problem is that I do not know `keyword` at compile time.

EDIT: I want to clarify to everyone that I know that what I want cannot be achieved by normal function overloading. I just wanted to know if it was possible to implement a function with a behaviour (which I nicknamed value-based function overloading, perhaps confusingly so) similar to process() above.

Comment: You can't use templates if you're using runtime values.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. "Overloading" is something that happens ***at compile time***. Obviously, at compile time it's not possible to infer what the value will be of some parameter at ***run time***. There are many techniques that can be used to simplify the task of checking a particular variable for a particular value, and then taking the appropriate action based on that.

Comment: *"but the problem is that I do not know keyword at compile time"* Then overloading can't help you. Maybe a map of function pointers can be used as a work-around.

Comment: @Ssm Varshavchik Yes I know, this is not function overloading. I called it "overloading", because in my opinion, the behaviour I want is similar to function overloading. Of course the implementation would be completely different. I was just wondering if someone had implemented this.

Comment: Can you give a somewhat more "real" example of what you're trying to do? You say you don't know the values until runtime, but if you're writing `void process_let()` in your code, then clearly you *do* know the value at runtime. And how would these different functions work differently?

Comment: @scohe001 I'm reading from a file. I know that, if I encounter the keyword let, I want to do something. But I don't know what the value of keyword is at compile time (which is the current word I'm reading from a file).

Comment: Of course "someone had implemented this", like I said there are many techniques to accomplish this, at run time, ranging from a series of `if` statements, to a `switch` statements, to lookup tables -- either a flat linear lookup table or an associative C++ container that does the lookup for you. There are many techniques available for implementing this, in general. Y

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Of course I know I can use a switch statement, but the point is that I find it unreadable and a pain to write. I tried implementing it myself, but failed. Thus I ask how this can implemented.

Comment: So what's the problem with having one big `dispatch(std::string str)` function that is just a big branching `if` that chooses which function to call based on the string passed?

Comment: @scohe001 Yes, I could write dispatch(std::string str), but I wondered if there was a way to automate this. I probably would have a lot of these types of functions...

Comment: can it be done? isnt the last snippet what you want to do? If yes, then thats how it can be done. If not it is unclear what you are asking for

Comment: What does "automate" mean in this context? Isn't writing a function to choose which function to call automating already? I'm confused what you're asking. If you have working code (ie: the `dispatch()` function with a big if) but you want critique on how to make it nicer, I'd suggest asking over on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't say a `switch` statement is the only possible way to do it. I mentioned at least three other ways. But, that's the way it's done, you are free to employ whichever approach you like best. Or, invent your own. In a vaguely related situation, one time, I ended up implementing an XML-based specification for grammar, with an XSLT stylesheet that robo-generated C++ code that implemented a parser for it. C++ can do anything. But only you can make C++ do something for you, and noone else.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 What I want to do is defining the functions like in snippet 1 and calling it in snippet 2. I don't want to write snippet 3 because I find it inelegant. But yes, the code in snippet 3 does what I want to do.

Comment: @scohe001 The question doesn't read like there's working code yet, so CR can't help here.

Comment: you cannot `switch` on string, otherwise you have to explain why you think it is inelegant

Comment: @Mast from the comment right above yours "*yes, the code in snippet 3 does what I want to do.*"

Comment: @scohe001 sorry partly my fault. Actually it is bogus code

Comment: @scohe001 That's a snippet, snippets are outlawed at CR.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think it is inelegant because I probably think it is inelegant because I probably would have many keywords and updating my switch statement every time I add a process() function for a new keyword seems redundant.

Comment: then please update your question to ask for that. There are only 2 keywords in your question

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get what you want automagically. If you want to call different functions depending on a runtime value then you need something like this:

```
void process_equal();
void process_let();
void process(const std::string& x) {
    if (x == "=") process_equal();
    else if (x == "let") process_let();
}
```

This seems to do what you want and frankly I don't see what is "inelegant" about it.

In case you have many keywords you might use a `std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function< void() >`. Though that wont prevent you from mapping the keywords to the functions.